# How to use JavaScript to play audio stream using srcObject property of Audio object?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

The specific is this: I use java to read an audio file on the back end, and then transfer it to the front end of the web page through websocket. On the web page, I want to play the data received by the websocket through the Audio () object. I know that I know the SrcObject property used for specific playback, but I don't know how to implement it?

Below is the code of my web page：

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="send()">play</button>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    var websocket = null;

    //whether support or not WebSocket
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
        websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
        websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
    }
    else {
        alert('The current browser does not support websocket');
    }

    function send() {
        websocket.send("play");
    }
    //
    websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var data = event.data;
        // console.log(new Float32Array(data));
        // play(data);
    };


    websocket.onopen = function () {
        console.log("onopen...");
    };

    websocket.onclose = function () {
        console.log("onclose...");
    };

    websocket.onerror = function () {
        console.log("onerror...");
    };

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        closeWebSocket();
    };

    function closeWebSocket() {
        websocket.close();
    }

    var context;
    var audio = new Audio();
    var promise;
    var flag = false;
    var b = false;
    var scriptProcessorNode;
    var gainNode;
    var streamAudioDestinationNode;
    // data: arrayBuffer
    function play(data) {
        if (context === undefined) {
            context = new AudioContext();
        }

        var buffer = context.createBuffer(2, 48000 * 2, 48000);
        buffer.copyToChannel(new Float32Array(data), 1, 1);
        var bufferSourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
        bufferSourceNode.buffer = buffer;

        if (!b) {
            scriptProcessorNode = context.createScriptProcessor();
            gainNode = context.createGain();
            streamAudioDestinationNode = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
            b = true;
        }
        bufferSourceNode.connect(scriptProcessorNode);
        scriptProcessorNode.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(streamAudioDestinationNode);

        audio.srcObject = streamAudioDestinationNode.stream;
        // audio.load();
        if (!flag) {
            promise = audio.play();
            console.log("method play");
            flag = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You server sends what exactly? Decoded PCM data?

Comment: The server reads the file and sends a byte array，code：`InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("static/test.wav").getInputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        int i = 0;
        while (i != -1) {
            i = inputStream.read(bytes, 0, 4096);
            try {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(bytes);
            } catch (EncodeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }`

Comment: wav file, but want to play pcm data on the web page

Comment: Then don't pass this to the BufferSourceNode, this expects already decoded PCM data. If your wav file contains raw PCM data, you can maybe send only that PCM data, meaning you have to extract it first. Alternatively, download the full file to a single ArrayBuffer and then audio_context.decodeAudioData() that full ArrayBuffer but you'll loose the streaming feature. An other solution to keep the streaming would have been to send feed a MediaSource, but AFAIK, nobody supports audio/wav. And maybe the best is to simply make your server accepts range-requests and expose this file like anybody.

Comment: That is, if I assign the decoded pcm data to the BufferSourceNode, is that all right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you don't then I'm sure it's not.

Comment: ok, i try again, thank you